# insert statement using current date column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting the following error while running this statement. I need to insert date functions in the columns. Any idea on this will be really helpful.

Error message:

> Error - ORA-20000: ORA-01843: not a valid month at pos 504 : TO_CHAR((LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1))),'DD/MM/YYYY')

Data Type: 
data type for ATT3 is DATE(7), 
ATT1 and ATT2 is VARCHAR2(400)

Query:

```
insert into ABC (X, Y, Z, ATT1, ATT2, ATT3)
VALUES ('G', 'H', 'I',
        TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1)),'Mon DD YYYY HH:MI AM'),
        TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Mon D YYYY HH:MI AM'),
        TO_CHAR((LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1))),'DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Comment: And the error says what...?

Comment: Error - ORA-20000: ORA-01843: not a valid month at pos 504 : TO_CHAR((LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1))),'DD/MM/YYYY')

Answer (score 1):

`TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Mon D YYYY HH:MI AM')` will give incorrect result. You need to change it to `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Mon DD YYYY HH:MI AM')`.

Please paste the structure of the table with the data types.

Comment: data type for ATT3 is  DATE(7), ATT1 and ATT2 VARCHAR2(400)

Comment: If ATT3 is a DATE, why are you trying to insert a string? Also you could replace `TO_CHAR((LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1))),'DD/MM/YYYY')` with `trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1`

Comment: Thanks @Boneist thats solved. mistake with the datatype.